# PHP - $database escape function

Tags: php, database, function, escaping

when i try send a private message between admins, after click on send button, returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function escape() on null in /members/site/sendMessage.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /members/site/sendMessage.php on line 7
```

but if i add manually "&msg=ok" in the url ends, works perfectly

this is content of file "sendMessage.php":

```
<?php
include_once("../../Account.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if($_SESSION['access'] < 9) die("Access Denied: You are not Admin!");  

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
   $_POST[$key] = $database->escape ($value);
}

$uid = (int) $_POST['uid'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$time = time();

$query = "INSERT INTO ".TB_PREFIX."mdata  SET target = $uid, owner = 1, topic = '$topic', message = '$message', viewed = 0, archived = 0, send = 0, time = $time, deltarget = 0, delowner = 0, coor = 0, report = 0";
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], $query) OR DIE (mysqli_errno($GLOBALS["link"]));

header("Location: ../../admin.php?p=Newmessage&uid=".$uid."&msg=ok");
?>
```

how to solve?!?

Comment: Hi, the cause is that `$database` isn't set, `$database = null`, where do you set `$database`.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).